# Cannot boot into macOS after attempting to remove Ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

### Issue + background

I have Ubuntu 18.04 dual booted on my 2015 MacBook Pro 15". I tried to remove the Ubuntu partition using Disk Utility, which failed ('internal error'). After a restart, the only boot option I see (holding the Option key) is EFI boot. I am able to boot into Ubuntu, but macOS is unavailable. I want to restore the ability to boot into macOS.

### Things I have tried

1. SMC and NVRAM reset: no effect
2. Internet recovery: when it prompts me to choose the disk to use for the install, it shows no disks
3. Disk Utility first aid: health checks pass on internal disk
4. Thunderbolt disk target mode: enters disk mode, but doesn't show up on other laptop connected

### Diagnostic output

`diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        2.0 GB     disk0s1

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF               200.8 GB   disk1s2
   3:           Linux Filesystem                         33.6 GB    disk1s3
   4:           Linux Filesystem                         16.4 GB    disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +5.2 MB     disk2

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk3

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk4

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk5

/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk6

/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk7

/dev/disk8 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk8

/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +12.6 MB    disk9

/dev/disk10 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +4.2 MB     disk10

/dev/disk11 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk11

/dev/disk12 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk12

/dev/disk13 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk13

/dev/disk14 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk14

/dev/disk15 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk15

/dev/disk16 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk16

/dev/disk17 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk17

/dev/disk18 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk18

/dev/disk19 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk19
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with MacBooks but the Disk Utility output is bewildering - it looks like there are 17 other disks of a few Mb in size? Assuming they are not important, if we look at disk1 it seems to be a 250Gb HD. The Linux partitions are recognised but the 'FFFFF etc' one is a large partition that Disk Utility can't recognise. Makes me think you have tried to delete the wrong partition (i.e the 200Gb Mac partition) and it failed because you were using it at the time and the error has corrupted it. The Mac Forums would be the best place to ask about repairing a corrupted Mac partition.

Comment: @pHeLiOn Thank you! I am 80% positive I clicked the right partition, can't rule out the other possibility...

Comment: If you can boot Ubuntu as it appears you can, there is a disk utility just called 'Disks' that might offer some details that help make it clearer, but I wouldn't recommend using a Linux utility to try and repair a Mac partition - see if you can find a Mac based solution on their forums about how to repair a corrupted partition or disk. Until then, your 'internet recovery' solution will not recognise the disk - the disk isn't damaged but the information on it is jumbled up making it unreadable to the program.

Comment: @pHeLiOn 'Disks' does recognize the disk has 4 partitions: EFI, the 200gb partition, 16 gigs linux swap and the 33 gig linux partition. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Had same exact problem and solved it w/ the help of https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/305712/343272

Comment: @DanAckerson Thank you so much, I in fact ended up using that answer. Couple days ago the problem reoccurred and I looked for the answer but couldn't find it. Now I have the link again...